# Writing value to c style string in struct

Tags: c++, struct, c-strings

For the life of me I can't figure out why the I can't write to a c style string inside of a struct.

College student - can't use string class, haven't learned pointers.

Help?  2 hours at trying to figure this out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void strCopy(char from[], char to[])
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        to[i] = from[i];
    }
}

struct card
{
    char suit[20];
    char rank[20];
    int cvalue;
    char location[20];
};

void printCard(card card)
{
    cout << card.rank << " of " << card.suit << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    // I don't think strCopy()'s the problem, I've used it with my last project.
    cout << "Test strCopy()" << endl;

    char str1[14] = "abcdefghijklm";
    char str2[14];

    strCopy(str1, str2);

    cout << "    " << str2 << endl << endl;

    // Now the negative.
    card one;
    one.cvalue = 2;
    strCopy("Somewhere", one.location);
    strCopy("Two", one.rank);
    strCopy("Hearts", one.suit);

    printCard(one); 
}
```

Comment: Your strCpy() function always writes 255 characters, but your char arrays hold only 20 characters.  So every time you call strCpy() you are writing off the end of the array and all over god-knows-what else...

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)` wat. Your strings are 14/20 `char`s long, you are positively nuking your stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // I don't think strCopy()'s the problem, I've used it with my last
>   project.

Wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
        to[i] = from[i]; 
}
```

copies 255 characters, however that's not what you meant.

If here :

```
strCopy(str1, str2);
cout << "    " << str2 << endl << endl;
```

Your're getting "correct" output, then you're just *unlucky*, since that invokes an undefined behavior, an you're writing off the end of the array.

Comment: Apparently I need help with strCopy() then. -___-.  Thanks!